# Auto refresh html canvas image not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

For my website, I need to redraw an image from server which is continuously updating. I found the solution and tried but it still does not auto refresh. I also tried adding a dummy string to my image(local0.jpg) so that the browser does not use cached image but no success. What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"> </canvas>
 <script>
 var imageObj=new Image();
 imageObj.src="local0.jpg?dummy=8484744"
 imageObj.onload=function()
 {
   var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
   var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
   ctx.drawImage(imageObj,0, 0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
   setTimeout(timedRefresh,1000);
 }
 function timedRefresh() 
 {
   imageObj.src = "local0.jpg?dummy=8484749"
 }
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You need to define the onload BEFORE you set the source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code

```js
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
    drawOnCanvas();
    setTimeout(timedRefresh, 1000);
  }
  // set src AFTER assigning load
imageObj.src = "local0.jpg?dummy=" + Math.random();

function timedRefresh() {
  imageObj.src = "local0.jpg?dummy=" + Math.random();
  //drawOnCanvas(); //flicker was due this line as it try to draw image load so i commented it... now it should work... 
}

function drawOnCanvas() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

Comment: It works but is there a way to do it without the flicker? Thanks a lot.

Comment: omg, I did the same but spent many hours because I had put imageObj.src = myImage + Math.random() * 1000 and forgotten about the ?dummy= part.  You're a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

your function `timedRefresh` add random values to image

```
 function timedRefresh() 
 {
   imageObj.src = "local0.jpg?dummy=" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
 }
```